# PHP "until date x" - Why are the 24 hours of the final day not included in the period?

Tags: php, days

I implemented a countdown in one of [our projects](http://www.klaustukai.lt/). As this was my first countdown I just realized that if I tell PHP:

```
$timeleft = strtotime('2013-10-31') - strtotime('now');
$daysleft = floor( $timeleft/(24*60*60) );
```

I get the time left to `2013-10-31 00:00` instead of the full day.

Why is it this way? I expected `2013-10-31 23:59:59` or `2013-11-01 00:00`

As an example from daily life: I have a rental contract for a car until 2013-10-31, or any contract, then I know that the rental period always **includes** the final day completely.

This might seem like a beginner's question but I would like to know the reason for this decision. Thank you for your ideas and experience.

PS: Is it the same in all programming languages?

Answer (score 2):

Then give a time to `strtotime` as well.

```
$timeleft = strtotime('2013-10-31 23:59:59') - strtotime('now');
```

**Why?**

Because when you say:

```
strtotime('2013-10-31');
```

That means the exact timestamp when that date started, which is equivalent to saying:

```
strtotime('2013-10-31 00:00:00');  // hence the missing 24 hours
```

**Edit**

In fact, saying `strtotime('now')` is just like saying `time()`, so you can remove that as well. And have it like:

```
$timeleft = strtotime('2013-10-31 23:59:59') - time();
```

> PS: Is it the same in all programming languages?

Its not a language limitation by any means, in any language. Its how you interpreted the function which generates time for you. After interpreting it correctly, send it the right values and it will work as you expect.

Comment: Is there another way of stating the final day which will include the 24 hours? For now I am using `$timeleft = strtotime('2013-10-31 + 1 day') - strtotime('now');`

Comment: +1 day is also fine, because start of next day will be equal to end of this day. You can also use http://www.php.net/mktime

Comment: One note why I am not using `time()`, I specify `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vilnius');` before to receive the correct local time. Using `time()` I would get the UTC which is not the same :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this will be the same as it is for money:
1 EURO = 1.00 EURO and not 1.50 EURO.

If the time of day matters, you should define it in both objects.

Answer (score 1):

As dates can be ambiguous, varying on time zones, daylight savings - even the architecture of the system that its running on, it is *recommended* to use the built in `DateTime` object.

There are numerous methods that can be used to manipulate the date, such as `DateTime::diff()` without all the manual calculations (ie. `floor( $timeleft/(24*60*60) );`).

So they might offer you better flexibility and accuracy when comparing date intervals and/or adding them together.

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-10-31');
$now  = new DateTime('today');
$diff = $date->diff($now);
$new  = $date->add($diff);

echo $new->format('Y-m-d H:i'); // 2013-11-01 00:00
```

Comment: How is this  `cleaner` than `$timeleft = strtotime('2013-10-31 23:59:59') - time();`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I've clarified what I meant, don't get me wrong, of course the built in date methods can be used, however, I often want to use dates more than once, where having to manually calculate them each time is repetitive and error prone

Comment: Cheers, good answer. I only meant point so that the word `cleaner` is replaced with `better`